# linux ls command to list file with certain characters in filename

Tags: linux, glob

I have files with name

```
145345000_abcd_20211201
100045430_abcd_20211130
143240000_abcd_20211129
```

in this `(_abcd_)` remains constant rest of the numbers in beginning and timestamp at the end changes every day.
i want to list all such files in a txt file
I am doing the following

```
ls ${mypath}/ > ${mypath}/my_list.txt
```

this will list all files and folder in mypath
where I want only file with (*abcd*) in file name
please guide. I Have tried many combinations already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep` to filter the files with `abcd` like this:

```sh
ls ${mypath}/ | grep abcd > ${mypath}/my_list.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use `ls` only like this:

```sh
ls -1 ${mypath}/*abcd* > ${mypath}/my_list.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, dont know what I was doing, It worked

Comment: I want to do this in regex also, can you help?